# What is the optimal strategy for a peace war game with unequal power and varying peace agreements?

Tags: game-theory

Consider a variant of the peace war game in which nation A can "harm" nation B much more than B can harm A if they both go to war, but each nation can also give the other nation tribute.

To formalize this, suppose each nation takes turns with A starting first and there being a total of 100 turns. When it is the nation's turn, the nation has 2 potential actions. One of them is to go to attack the other nation. When A attacks B, A has a payoff of -1 and B has a payoff of -10. When B attacks A, both have a payoff of -1. The other potential action is "parameterized" such as the nation can choose any real number > 0 (this is the "tribute"). In this case, for the nation giving tribute, the payoff = 2 - the number selected, and for the other nation the payoff = 2 + the number selected.

What's the optimal strategy?

Comment: You still haven't defined the game sufficiently. What moves are available to A? Presumably to split the tribute and accept peace.  Now does B have to choose, or can B make a counterproposal?  Math is much more restrictive than real life, but it can help your thinking a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a game of [chicken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_(game))  A can tell B he will only accept tribute of $4$ for peace and B is better off accepting than fighting.  B can tell A he will offer $1.001$ for peace and A is better off accepting than fighting.  You did not detail how the game is played, so the strategies are not defined.

Comment: What else is there to about how the game is played? Both nations move simultaneously and the game lasts arbitrarily long (Say, 100 turns). For the specific payoff, look at the examples in the question.

Comment: Moving simultaneously was not specified.  Also the fact that it is a repeated game (not one time). Both make a change in the optimal strategy.  Please define the question carefully.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've now realized that the game is essentially war of attrition, which has already been solved. However, I don't know the optimal move when moves aren't simultaneous, so I shall edit my question accordingly.

Comment: As you wrote the question, it is not at all a war of attrition-there is one selection of alternatives after a phase of making proposals.  Each side either accepts the proposal or goes to war. This supports my claim that the process is not well defined.  I imagined that each side proposes a division of the tribute, then they simultaneously choose peace or war.  What is the process?

Comment: Man, I'm really messing up. Yes you're right. After I looked into the game more, I realized it was different. Anyways, at each move, the nation whose move it is can either go to war, or give the other nation an arbitrary real quantity of tribute.

Comment: I've rewritten the question to explain the problem. Note that each nation can only give as tribute numbers that are at least 0, which I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal strategy seems to be to always offer the minimum tribute of 0, which means both countries get 2 payout. This maximizes your own country's payout.